# ASP.NET Core Static File Return as Base64 Encoded

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I've created a new ASP.NET Core web app `dotnet new webapp`.
I've added `d3.js` library to it, that is fine.

When I try to run the calendar example it tries to load a CSV file from the server, I've added this file into the `wwwroot` directory, but when the response comes back from the dev-server, it is base64 encoded.

This cause the JSON parsing of d3 to break.

[This is the GitHub repo of the project if you want to run and see the error](https://github.com/ido-ran/aspnet-core-static-data).

Any ideas why Kestrel is encoding the file this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `d3.csv()` does but it could possibly that you just need to set the `Content-Type` properly. By default, `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` is used for file types that are unknown.

In your `Configure` method in Startup.cs, set a mapping for the .csv file type.

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

// Add csv mapping
provider.Mappings[".csv"] = "text/csv"; // Try text/plain if text/csv doesn't work

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```